# Section on top of section iphone table

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ipad, grouped-table

I am building a sectioned table, and it is showing up with what looks to be a section on top of a section.  You can see on the image that there is a white line under each section.

[The image](http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/6364/screenshot20100630at121.png)

Here is the code I have to build the table:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [alertList count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier;

 if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
 {
  CellIdentifier = @"CellLandscape";
 }
 else
 {
  CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] 
    autorelease];

  //cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  CGRect frame;

  if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  {
   frame.origin.x = 370;
   //titleFrame.size.width = 320;
  }
  else
  {
   frame.origin.x = 220;
   //titleFrame.size.width = 220;
  }

  frame.origin.y = 5;
  frame.size.height = 15;
  frame.size.width = 74;

  UILabel *instLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  instLabel.tag = 1;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:instLabel];
  [instLabel release];
    }


 // Configure the cell.
 Alert *p = [alertList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

 UILabel *instLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
 instLabel.text = [p docDate];
 instLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [instLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]];

 NSString *path;

 if ([[p subscription] isEqual:@"Y"])
 {
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"watchlist_on" ofType:@"png"];
 }
 else
 {
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"watchlist_off" ofType:@"png"];
 }

 //NSLog(@"%@", path);

 cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.847 green:0 blue: 0 alpha: 1];
 [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
 cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [p Name]];

 cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 10]];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [p docTitle];

 cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 10]];
 //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [p docDate];

 //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
 cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

 //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

 ///    [cell addSubview:imgView];

 //cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@ G: %@\nDOB: %@ Inst: %@", [p lastName], [p firstName], [p gender], 
 //        [p birthDate], [p inst]];

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

 //only 1 alert at a time

 //make doc list from alert object
 Document *documentList1 = [[Document alloc] init];
 self.documentList = documentList1;
 [documentList1 setTitle:[p docTitle]];
 [documentList1 setUniqueId:[p uniqueId]];
 [documentList1 setDate:[p docDate]];
 [documentList1 setRepoOID:[p repoOid]];
 [documentArray addObject:documentList];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The image link is now dead making the question less clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the table view's separator style to either single line or none - you probably have it on single line etched.